# SharePoint Foundation 2010 into Web Platform Installer

Tags: installation

Guys, I have a great idea - ask Microsoft to include SharePoint Foundation 2010 into Web Platform Installer. It'll be very usefull for all community. I do it by twitter: http://twitter.com/butaji/status/19322524336. What are you think about this petition?

Comment: This is really more of a community wiki-type post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there are some architectural considerations frequently overlooked.  Even a Foundation 2010 system should be planned.  I would hate to find a company with 10 web servers each hosting 10 single server SharePoint farms with local databases.

Comment: I agree with you, but there are many ways to check out sharepoint installation and make it possible only one time, for example like WPI installed one instance of SQL Server

Comment: The best scenario for checking out SharePoint is a web-based VM trial.  I know MS has some online training that already does this.  When a user signs up, they provision a new VM from a standard image and give the user an account to use.  This is all done in a few minutes, and there is no need to worry about how to install it or transitioning from that poorly planned temporary box to a real production environment.

Comment: Now SharePoint already on WPI!

Answer (score 1):

Agree with Mike, having SharePoint in the Web Platform Installer will certainly make even more bad installations of SharePoint (which of course make consultants busy :-), aka Standalone installations.

The standalone option is there for one single purpose - and that is trial and demo (and AFAIK MS added that feature to satisfy some research companies when they said SP was to cumbersome to install). 
If SP was added to WPI it would certainly make companies beleive that the installation is production ready - which it is not when installed in Standalone mode.